# Whats the quote of hashem helping?

Tags: sources-mekorot

I know the basic context of what I'm looking for in English, something like, "If you try as much as the eye of a needle, then Hashem will help you."

Can someone help me figure out the actual Maamar Chazal (saying) in Hebrew? Thanks a million!

Comment: I edited your post to fix some typos and grammar issues. In the future, it's a lot easier for people to read your posts if they are punctuated correctly.

Answer (score 10):

It's a Medrash ([Shir Hashirim Rabbah](https://www.responsa.co.il/wiki.aspx?docId=0200800045800000000000000000&docId=0200800045800000000000000000) 5). It says

> רבי יסא אמר, אמר הקב"ה לישראל בני פתחו לי פתח אחד של תשובה כחודה של מחט ואני פותח לכם פתחים שיהיו עגלות וקרניות נכנסות בו
>
> Rabbi Yossi says that Hashem says to the Jews "My children open for me an opening of Teshuva the size of the point of a needle and I'll open for you doorways which are large enough that wagons can enter".

Comment: @shifra you can also click the checkmark by an answer you've think helped you the most or best addressed your concerns to help others see it

Comment: +1. Isn't there another wording, about פתחו של אולם (or maybe של היכל) too, though?

Comment: Please check that [my edit](/posts/83435/revisions) is acceptable to you and re-edit otherwise.

Comment: @msh210 פתחו של אולם is quoted in numerous sefarim, but you won't find it in any Midrash. There must have been another version which was lost.

Comment: @msh210 Sefas Emes to Bereishis, in his piece on Chanukah, quotes the Midrash as בזאת השער הקטן יפתח להם פתחו של היכל ואולם. Or in Vayikra in his piece on Shabbos HaGadol ואני אפתח לכם כפתחו של אולם. Don't be surprised that I pulled it out of my back pocket at 2 in the morning - I just plugged the phrase into Sefaria. Like Jay said - everyone uses that phrase, but the original doesn't.

Comment: @Jay ^^^^^^^^^^